# Read POST webhook PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to read the contents of a webhook notification in php. The content of the request is in the link below:

[Link POST](http://requestb.in/17hfpib1?inspect)

> **HEADERS:**
>     Pragma: no-cache
>     X-Request-Id: fec7f2ea-ae08-4fc1-9f81-b7ed9b976100
>     X-Newrelic-Transaction: PxQDWVNWCgBWBlJWVldRV1dUFB8EBw8RVU4aVgANAQAAA1tSBQBVBFUFUkNKQQtVVlNTUVZQFTs=
>     Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
>     Connect-Time: 2
>     Connection: close
>     Content-Length: 931
>     Cache-Control: no-cache
>     User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_72
>     Accept-Encoding: gzip
>     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>     Via: 1.1 vegur
>     X-Newrelic-Id: UgcDUFdVGwQAXFdRBAU=
>     Host: requestb.in
>     Total-Route-Time: 0
>
> **FORM/POST PARAMETERS:** 
>   data: { "event": "PAYMENT_UPDATED", "payment": { "object": "payment", "id": "pay_158657847699", "customer": "cus_artujit2nfYe", "value": 160.0, "netValue": 155.75, "originalValue": null, "nossoNumero": "34271724", "description": "", "billingType": "BOLETO", "status": "PENDING", "dueDate": "21/12/2016", "paymentDate": null, "invoiceUrl": "", "boletoUrl": "", "invoiceNumber": "00507815", "externalReference": null, "deleted": false } }

I tried unsuccessfully through the line code: $datasrc = $_POST;

I also tried to read with $ _REQUEST unsuccessfully.

How to read the content in php?

Comment: Ok, but how do you retrieve the data? If your PHP page is retrieving data using $_POST or $_REQUEST, it means that data has been sent to that page... How does that happen? Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: Notification posts are automatically triggered for a previously declared page. My question is precisely this. How do I recover the data?

Answer (score 0):

No clue what webhook is or does. But if it is sent as as POST request to a page in PHP, the data posted will be present in the $_POST array.

To see what's in it: `var_dump($_POST);` will show you the array and it's structure.

To get the value of a specific key: `$variable = $_POST['key'];` will do the trick.

If I interpret the stuff you posted correctly the json encoded content should be in `$_POST['data'];` .

To decode the json encoded string, PHP has helpful functions such as [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

`$data=json_decode($_POST['data'], true);` should give you a PHP array with the data.